# Turn a String to an array Declaration

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

In JS :
I have this string ="[36.79025,3.01642],[36.71477,2.99761]";
I want it to be turned To a real Array =[[36.79025,3.01642],[36.71477,2.99761]];
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var string = "[36.79025,3.01642],[36.71477,2.99761]";
var arr = JSON.parse(`[${string}]`);
console.log(arr);
```

```
[[36.79025,3.01642],[36.71477,2.99761]]
```